# Wrong outputs in Decimal to binary conversion after input of 1024?

Tags: c++, c, error-handling

My code works fine till 1024, but bigger values than 1024 gives wrong output, please help:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int dec,i=1;
    int rem=0;
    long long int result=0;

    scanf("%d",&dec);

    while(dec!=0)
    {
        rem=dec%2;
        result = result +rem*i;

        dec=dec/2;
        i=i*10;

    }
    printf("%I64u",result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't write your decimal-to-binary converter such that it stores its output in an `int`.  Not only does it artificially limit the range of numbers you can convert, it's also pretty meaningless.

Please write your converter to store its output as a *string*.  That will work much, much better.

Comment: 1024 is to large for int. 1024=0b10000000000. Now you are trying to store 10000000000 in a long long.  This would be ok but you use int variables for calculations.

Comment: From a programming language perspective, binary and decimal are **text formats**. The variable `dec` is not in decimal. It's just a value. The code uses `scanf` to **translate** text from the console into a numeric value. A function that converts that value to a binary (or any other) **text representation** should produce the result in the form of text.

Answer (score 1):

The code should accumulate the binary value in a string. Since this is cross-posted to C and C++, I suppose a C solution is appropriate (in C++ I'd use `std::string`, and the bookkeeping would be somewhat simpler):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int rem=0;
char result[sizeof(long long)*CHAR_BITS+1];
int dec,i=sizeof(result);
result[--i] = '\0';

scanf("%d",&dec);
while(dec!=0)
{
    rem=dec%2;
    result[--i] = rem + '0';
    dec=dec/2;
}
printf("%s",result + i);

return 0;
```

}

(Caution: not tested)

Answer (score -1):

Here you are

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int dec = 0;
    long long int i = 1;
    long long int result = 0;

    scanf( "%d", &dec );

    do
    {
        int rem = dec % 2;
        result = result + rem * i;

        i *= 10;

    } while ( dec /= 2 );

    printf( "%I64u", result );

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the variable `i` is declared as having the type `int`. So the result value of the expression `i *= 10` or of the expression `rem * i` will be calculated as objects of the type `int` not as objects of the type `long long int`.

If to enter `1024` then the output is

```
10000000000
```

In general your approach is wrong because the size of the type `long long int` in any case is restricted and will be unable to represent all posible integer values in the binary notation.

You could use either a character or an integer array of digits instead of an object of the type `long long int`.

Comment: This doesn't address the general overflow problem. It just pushes the possible overflow out to higher values. Consider translating `INT_MAX` when `int` and `long long` are the same size...

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes, but it is evident that he should limit the range of entered values using his approach I answered his question why for the value 1024 he gets an invalid result.

Comment: Well, sure. And with the original code, the limit should be that the input is less than 1024. Voila: the problem has been fixed by definition. But it still exists.